# Why is my table name not valid?

Tags: sql, schema, sql-server-ce

Here is the create statement:

```
create table dbmonitor.DBMON_DATABASE_TYPE (
        DATABASE_TYPE_ID BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
       DispName NVARCHAR(255) null,
       primary key (DATABASE_TYPE_ID)
    )
```

and this is the error I get:

```
13:40:57,685 ERROR [TestRunnerThread] SchemaExport [(null)]- The table name is not valid. [ Token line number (if known) = 1,Token line offset (if known) = 24,Table name = DBMON_DATABASE_TYPE ]
The table name is not valid. [ Token line number (if known) = 1,Token line offset (if known) = 24,Table name = DBMON_DATABASE_TYPE ]
```

Comment: Can't you just choose another name for your table and be done with it?

Comment: I see you accepted an answer (mine), but which was the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibilities:

1. Is `dbmonitor` the name of your database? You can't put a `.` in a table name.
2. Do you mean `CREATE TABLE dbmonitor.dbo.DBMON_DATABASE_TYPE`?
3. Did you try `CREATE TABLE DBMON_DATABASE_TYPE`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if `dbmonitor` is meant to be a schema name, but according to the documentation for the SQL CE [CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173393%28SQL.90%29.aspx) statement, you cannot include a schema name with the table name.

Contrast this for SQL Server 2005 Compact Edition (just showing the initial part of the statement),

```
CREATE TABLE table_name 
   ( { < column_definition > | < table_constraint > } [ ,...n ] 
   )
```

with this for SQL Server 2008:

```
CREATE TABLE 
    [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly an answer for this question's criteria , but for those who might get here :

this error can also happen when you try to use `EntityFramework.Extended` library with `Sql Server CE`. It seems that they are not compatible.

check these links :

https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/issues/35

https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/issues/11